# How to make handle action for disable option in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to make custom event and dispatch him, when user click on disabled option in react-select dropdown. But any events dont work in this case, because input is disabled. Any ideas how to make this? Maybe i can wrap option in div, if this option disabled?

```
<Select
  value={this.state.cityOptions}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={this.state.cityList}
  styles={customStyles}
  placeholder="City"
  name="cityOptions"
  isSearchable={false}
  isOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which lib of Select do you use?

Because it depends on your select library, this is not a full example. Try to convert your options and pass them to

```
  handleDisabledOptionClick = ({ event, option }) => {
    console.log('Option is disabled: ', { option })
  }

  const options = this.state.cityList.map((option) => {
    return (
      <option
        disabled={option.disabled}
        onClick={(event) => option.disabled && handleDisabledOptionClick({
          event,
          option,
        })}
      >
        {option.label}
      </option>
    )
  })

  <Select
    value={this.state.cityOptions}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    styles={customStyles}
    placeholder="City"
    name="cityOptions"
    isSearchable={false}
    isOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled}
  >
    {options}
  </Select>
```

Comment: i use react-select library, i was try append options as a child (into Select), but component doesn't render options

Comment: If you want to use this particular library, then you will have to thoroughly examine its code. But this does not guarantee success. The second way is to write the component code yourself. It is very simple. For example you can use this select https://codepen.io/SergioBelevskij/pen/PLjjqg to improve its for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With `react-select` I recommend you to use a custom `Option` component like this:

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = props => {
    console.log(props);
  };

  const Option = props => {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          if (props.data.isDisabled) {
            handleClick(props);
          }
        }}
      >
        <components.Option {...props} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select components={{ Option }} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `options` structure is the following one:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "option 1",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "option 2",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "option 3",
    value: 3,
    isDisabled: true
  }
];
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvzqpx176w).